# Set a theano placeholder to another theano placeholder at the construction of symbolic graph?

Tags: theano

My question is that if it is possible to define a theano symbolic graph in which a placeholder variable is set to some other placeholder variables?
For example, I construct a symbolic graph `f(x)` with one placeholder variable `x`. Now, I construct another symbolic graph `g(y1, y2) = f(y1) + f(y2)` using the predefined graph `f` where `y1,y2` are two new placeholder variables. That is, I set `x = y1` to get `f(y1)` and set `x = y2` to get `f(y2)`. Is this valid? And if so, the graph `g` acts as if it has two different placeholder variables (`y1`, `y2`), right?

Thanks in advance.
-T

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using theano.clone to replace a subgraph of a graph with another subgraph. Here is an example that I would like to post here for future reference:

```
import numpy as np 
import theano 
import theano.tensor as T 

a = T.scalar('a')
b = T.scalar('b')
w = theano.shared(value = 1., name='w')
c = a * w + b
f = theano.function([a,b], c)
theano.printing.pydotprint(f, outfile="_f.png", var_with_name_simple=True)

x1 = T.scalar('x1')
x2 = T.scalar('x2')
y1 = theano.clone(c, replace={a:x1})
y2 = theano.clone(c, replace={a:x2})

y = y1 + y2

g = theano.function([x1,x2, b], y)
theano.printing.pydotprint(g, outfile="_g.png", var_with_name_simple=True)

print(g(1,2,3)) # print 9
```

- The compiled graph of f:

[image: The compiled graph of f]

- The compiled graph of g: 
  [image: The compiled graph of g]